# Difference between assigning a int to getchar() and using getchar() without it

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

while doing a exercise in K&R book(The C programming language 2nd edition) i ran into a problem i do not seem to grasp and understand. Namely the exercise was to write a program that counts spaces,tabs and new lines(at the very beginning of the book). I am writing in debian/gedit(dunno if this is relevant).

The code that i wrote is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)

{

int nb = 0;         
int nt = 0;         
int nl = 0;         

while(getchar() != EOF)

    {
    if(getchar() == ' ')
        ++nb;
    if(getchar() == '\t')
        ++nt;
    if(getchar() == '\n') 
        ++nl;
    }
printf("%d\n%d\n%d\n", nb, nt, nl);

return 0;
}
```

Now when i execute the program it does not count spaces or tabs and in general does not behave as intended.

Than i checked for the correct answer in the books and i saw that they have and int c assigned to getchar() namely

```
while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    if(c == ' ')
     ++nb;
```

and so on.

Now what i don't understand is why is it important to assign a int in this case c to getchar() and than use it in IF brackets. Should the way i wrote it not work the same?

Now as i understand int c is not a definite value or an exact value so to me as a beginner it all seamed as the only purpose of assigning it is so we do not have to write getchar() every time and can simply write c.

Also is there a specific desired condition where you should or should not assign a int to getchar()?

Executing the code as they wrote it gives the expected result but to be honest i don't seem to understand what is really happening here.

Any kind of help is appreciated, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now what i don't understand is why is it important to assign a int in this case c to getchar() and than use it in IF brackets.

It is indeed important to assign `c` to `getchar`.

```
while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
```

what it actually does is three steps:

- `getchar()` get a character from standard input stream (`stdin`).
- The character read is then assign to `c`.
- Then `c` is compared to `EOF`.

> Should the way i wrote it not work the same?

```
while(getchar() != EOF)

    {
    if(getchar() == ' ')
        ++nb;
```

No. Your code does not have expected behaviour because you call `getchar` several times inside your `while` loop. What your code actually does is:

- Read the **first char** from standard input `stdin`.
- Compare that first char to EOF.
- Then if it's NOT `EOF`, **read a second char** from stdin.
- Compare the **second char** to `' '`.
- And so on.

You can see why it's not expected behaviour because what you need is to read a **single char** and compare to all values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, helped me a lot to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

It's because *every* `getchar()` call reads *another* character from the input. So you can't use it later to check for white-spaces.

> what i don't understand is why is it important to assign a int in this
>   case c to getchar() and than use it in IF brackets. Should the way i
>   wrote it not work the same?

You need to assign to a variable because you want to use it *later*. The way you wrote won't work for the problem you attempt to solve.

> Also is there a specific desired condition where you should or should
>   not assign a int to getchar()?

No. There's no rule whether you should assign or not. It depends on the specific problem you solve. You should assign if you want to use/check the value later.

For example, if you simply want to ignore a whitespace then:

```
int c = gethchar();
getchar(); // Simply discard one character from inout
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `getchar()` repeatedly in each `if` test.

You'll miss out a lot of potential matches as each call to `getchar` consumes another character from the input buffer.

You ought to assign the return of `getchar()` to a variable, once per loop, and test that. `while((c = getchar()) != EOF)` will work well for that, and test for `c` in the loop body.

Answer (score 0):

> Now what i don't understand is why is it important to assign a int in this case c to getchar() and than use it in IF brackets. Should the way i wrote it not work the same?

First of all here `c` is *not* assigned to `getchar()` rather `getchar()` is assigned to `c`.

Moving on, here we are simply storing the character read by `getchar()` in `c` to check whether entered character is  (space) or `\n` or whatever in subsequent code.

As according to `man getchar`

> getchar()  return the character read as an unsigned char cast to an int or EOF on end of file or error.

---

If we didn't store the character read by `getchar()` in `c` and used separate `getchar()` function calls in subsequent code then, we lose what `getchar()` read in the beginning as well as in other `getchar()` calls.